# Have gpg-agent start with ssh key file when available, falling back to gpg keys?

Tags: ssh, gnupg, ssh-agent, gpg-agent

On linux (Fedora) using bash, I have setup the GnuPG `gpg-agent` to act as the `ssh-agent` successfully. When authenticating over **ssh**, the agent tries the **gpg keys first** then falls back to the ssh keyfile **~/.ssh/id_rsa**. Is there a way to reverse the order of tried keys?

My preference is to try `~/.ssh/id_rsa` first, then to try gpg keys in the order specified in `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol`.

I don't want to prevent gpg keys from being used so adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` to `~/.ssh/sshconfig` does not seem like an option.

Also, I trust the security of my `~/.ssh` directory and do not want to be asked for a password when using the ssh key, so using `ssh-add` to import the key into `GnuPG` is not the answer either becuase it requires a password.

Comment: Check the "Remember password in gnome-keyring" box in GnuPG, and you won't be asked for the password anymore?

Comment: @grawity While this is a valid answer when using Gnome, I'd prefer not to add to my already long list of password managers - especially one that is tied to a specific desktop or that requires a window manager in general.